# Repeated crashing ableton.exe because of memory being accessed by .dll that doesn't exist. How can I fix this?

Tags: crash, windbg, ableton-live

Ableton Live 10 is crashing often. I am opening the crash reports and opening the .dmp files in WinDBG. There are recurring themes:

So I was seeing a memory access violation due to a VST drum plug-in. I uninstalled the plug-in and deleted the .dll files. Things got better, but If I pushed things pretty hard, usually in combination with another specific VST it seems, I will crash. Again the same big_bang_drums_64.dll is implicated, even though it no longer exists in the system. Also, I have at this point deleted all config and pref files, and am working out of a completely new VST folder, but still ref_null_ptr and access exceptions.

I re-install the plugin to see if maybe that corrects the issue, but no luck. Ableton Live crash reports contain multiple dump files in each report. For me, it seems like 3 .dmp for the day/time of crash, plus maybe 5 or six going back several months to september. This seems to be pretty consistent, though I do not know whay the older .dmp files or if they have some significance attached to them.

I am pretty new to WinDBG and crash dumps and all that. So I think I've gone about as far as I can, and could use some help solving this problem.

Here are excerpts from the 3 "day of crash" .dmp files:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Loading Dump File [C:\Users\justg\AppData\Roaming\Ableton\Live Reports\Ableton Crash Report 2021-01-25 143822 Live 10.1.30\Crash\Live_10.1.30_2020-10-27_fc0fea66dc_2021_01_05__15_15_35.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available
************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 18363 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Tue Jan  5 15:35:34.000 2021 (UTC - 8:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:20:00.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(2ba8.3b84): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
ntdll!NtGetContextThread+0x14:
00007ffd`a505e484 c3              ret
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for atidxx64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ReWire.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for amdihk64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for WrapPersist64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MaxPlug.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for atiumd64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Creative Intent Tantrum (x64).vst3
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Pink_VST.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for focusritepcieasio64.dll

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : AV.Fault
    Value: Read

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2437

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on DESKTOP-AC2AQHC

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 22450

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 441

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 1200

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: 19h1_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-03-18T12:02:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.18362.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 1.0.0.1


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

OS_BUILD_LAYERS: 1

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=3fdff96c20cc9b8b rcx=000000010bee8b28
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000145acfae0 rdi=000000000014f0a0
rip=0000000141adfb78 rsp=000000000014efe0 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=00000001458d23f0  r9=00000001449b6ce0 r10=0000000000000005
r11=000000000014f040 r12=0000000000000000 r13=000000000005040e
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1adfb78:
00000001`41adfb78 48394b38        cmp     qword ptr [rbx+38h],rcx ds:3fdff96c`20cc9bc3=????????????????
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000141adfb78 (Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x0000000001adfb78)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffffffffff
Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff

PROCESS_NAME:  Ableton Live 10 Suite.exe

READ_ADDRESS:  ffffffffffffffff 

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  ffffffffffffffff

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`0014efe0 00000001`41adffed     : 00000001`0bee8b28 00000001`45acfae0 00000000`00000000 00007ffd`8af243e0 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1adfb78
00000000`0014f020 00000001`428c0793     : 00000001`0bee8b28 00000000`00000000 00000001`449b6c38 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1adffed
00000000`0014f070 00000001`40ac223f     : 00000001`0bee98d0 00000001`0bee98d0 00000000`0014f340 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initMxDManager+0x2ff613
00000000`0014f0c0 00000001`41c195f4     : 00000001`0beebb30 00000001`0beebb30 00000000`0014f340 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0xac223f
00000000`0014f100 00000001`40a88714     : 00000001`0beebd40 00007ffd`8af243e0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x18874
00000000`0014f140 00000001`4291d8a8     : 00000000`00000000 00000001`0beebb30 00000000`0014f340 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0xa88714
00000000`0014f190 00000001`41c195f4     : 00000001`0beeda98 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initMxDManager+0x35c728
00000000`0014f1d0 00000001`40a88714     : 00000001`0beedce8 00000001`40a876ad 00000000`d637b570 00007ffd`537072af : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x18874
00000000`0014f210 00000001`41c195f4     : 00000001`0beefa60 00000001`0beef7c8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0xa88714
00000000`0014f260 00000001`40a88714     : 00000001`0beef990 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000001`40a87671 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x18874
00000000`0014f2a0 00000001`4291d7f8     : 00000000`00000000 00000001`440e0d88 00000000`00000000 00000001`41c20477 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0xa88714
00000000`0014f2f0 00000001`41c202ac     : 00000001`4447ad70 00000000`00000137 00000001`00000000 00000000`3fffff01 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initMxDManager+0x35c678
00000000`0014f340 00000001`41c20012     : 00000000`000000be 00000000`3fffffff 00000001`08ffcd01 00000001`08ffcd00 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x1f52c
00000000`0014f3a0 00000001`41cfe29f     : 00000001`0beefa60 00000001`08ffcd00 00000000`3fffffff 00000001`08ffcd00 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x1f292
00000000`0014f3e0 00000001`41c21685     : 00000001`09d6d960 00000001`41c1fef7 00000001`0beefa60 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0xfd51f
00000000`0014f410 00000001`41c216f2     : 00000001`0beefa60 00000001`09d6d820 00000001`09d6d820 00000000`3fffffff : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x20905
00000000`0014f450 00000001`41c15fd3     : 00000001`2c4b3b78 00000001`00000000 00000001`0beefdc8 00000001`2dfe9b80 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x20972
00000000`0014f490 00000001`41c14e0e     : 00000000`00000000 00000016`0000002c 00000000`0014f5b8 00000001`0bee8b28 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x15253
00000000`0014f520 00000001`428c1797     : 80000000`80000000 00007ffd`8a73290f 000088a9`eff53b42 00000000`00000401 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x1408e
00000000`0014f570 00000001`428c15e1     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014f640 00000000`0014f800 00000000`30a51ed0 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initMxDManager+0x300617
00000000`0014f5f0 00000001`41adf335     : 00000000`fc395ae0 00000000`0014f6d0 00000000`02e40100 00000000`02e40100 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initMxDManager+0x300461
00000000`0014f640 00000001`41adfe98     : 00000000`02e40100 00000001`41c55307 00000000`01b9a65e 00000000`00032000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1adf335
00000000`0014f690 00000001`41c6e639     : 00000000`c33ba680 00000000`000145d8 00000000`0014f880 00000000`0014f880 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1adfe98
00000000`0014f760 00000001`41c6e880     : 00000000`00028bb1 00000000`ec6fe000 00000000`00000000 00000000`ec6fe000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x6d8b9
00000000`0014f7e0 00000001`41c6eb6e     : 00000000`0014f8a0 00000000`00000401 ffffffff`fffffffe 00000140`e5637b38 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x6db00
00000000`0014f860 00000001`41c6bd5c     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000401 00000140`e4c64dc9 00009fe0`0000027f : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x6ddee
00000000`0014f8f0 00007ffd`a33a5c1d     : 00000001`40826890 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00006010 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x6afdc
00000000`0014f920 00007ffd`a33a57ec     : 00000000`00000388 00000001`41c6bcf0 00000000`0005040e 00000000`80000000 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2bd
00000000`0014fab0 00007ffd`a33b1f83     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00028bb1 00006010`00000000 : user32!DispatchClientMessage+0x9c
00000000`0014fb10 00007ffd`a5060464     : 00000000`00000070 ffffffff`ffffffff ffffffff`ffffffff 00007ffd`a33a5aa4 : user32!_fnDWORD+0x33
00000000`0014fb70 00007ffd`a2a210c4     : 00007ffd`a33a94f2 00007ffd`a2a21164 00000000`0014fc78 00000000`0014fc48 : ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
00000000`0014fbf8 00007ffd`a33a94f2     : 00007ffd`a2a21164 00000000`0014fc78 00000000`0014fc48 00000000`00030000 : win32u!NtUserPeekMessage+0x14
00000000`0014fc00 00007ffd`a33a9459     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00b56a40 00000000`00000000 00000000`007b0484 : user32!_PeekMessage+0x42
00000000`0014fc70 00000001`41c26f20     : 00000000`00000000 00000001`40000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014fdb0 : user32!PeekMessageW+0x149
00000000`0014fce0 00000001`416afca9     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00001fa0 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x261a0
00000000`0014fea0 00000001`4157fd73     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x16afca9
00000000`0014fef0 00007ffd`a36c7c24     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x157fd73
00000000`0014ff30 00007ffd`a502d4d1     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000000`0014ff60 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


SYMBOL_NAME:  Ableton_Live_10_Suite+1adfb78

MODULE_NAME: Ableton_Live_10_Suite

IMAGE_NAME:  Ableton Live 10 Suite.exe

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Ableton_Live_10_Suite.exe!Unknown

OS_VERSION:  10.0.18362.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  1.0.0.1

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {9430be48-f850-ff85-3085-58b90c4cf8e7}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

AND:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\justg\AppData\Roaming\Ableton\Live Reports\Ableton Crash Report 2021-01-25 143822 Live 10.1.30\Crash\Live_10.1.30_2020-10-27_fc0fea66dc_2021_01_07__10_08_53.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 18363 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Thu Jan  7 15:01:47.000 2021 (UTC - 8:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 4:52:56.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(298c.539c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
ntdll!NtGetContextThread+0x14:
00007ffd`a505e484 c3              ret
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for atidxx64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ReWire.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for amdihk64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for focusritepcieasio64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for WrapPersist64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MaxPlug.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for atiumd64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Creative Intent Tantrum (x64).vst3
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for TriceraChorus.vst3
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Pink_VST.dll

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : AV.Dereference
    Value: NullClassPtr

    Key  : AV.Fault
    Value: Write

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2515

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on DESKTOP-AC2AQHC

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 16601

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 475

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 17576

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: 19h1_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-03-18T12:02:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.18362.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 1.0.0.1


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

OS_BUILD_LAYERS: 1

NTGLOBALFLAG:  4000

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=00000000525cd188 rbx=000000005b45a520 rcx=000000000000012c
rdx=000000005b45a5c8 rsi=000000005b45a5c8 rdi=000000005b2f2340
rip=00000001408b1b22 rsp=000000000014f180 rbp=0000000145ac2d00
 r8=000000005b2f2340  r9=0000000000000015 r10=000000005b45a520
r11=000000005b2f23e8 r12=0000000000000014 r13=00000000b570b550
r14=00000000b570b4e0 r15=00000000b570b5a8
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x8b1b22:
00000001`408b1b22 832901          sub     dword ptr [rcx],1 ds:00000000`0000012c=????????
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000001408b1b22 (Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x00000000008b1b22)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 000000000000012c
Attempt to write to address 000000000000012c

PROCESS_NAME:  Ableton Live 10 Suite.exe

WRITE_ADDRESS:  000000000000012c 

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000000000012c

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`0014f180 00000001`408aeea7     : 00000000`0014f2c9 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014f268 00000001`4085a4aa : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x8b1b22
00000000`0014f1b0 00000001`422cb61b     : 00000000`b570b5a8 00000000`00000000 00000000`b570b448 00000000`0014f200 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x8aeea7
00000000`0014f200 00000001`41bb5b5a     : 00000000`b570b300 00000000`00487476 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014f338 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initlive_io+0x297cbb
00000000`0014f330 00000001`41bc1b34     : 00000000`b570b398 00000000`00000001 00000000`2a591828 00000000`2a591828 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1bb5b5a
00000000`0014f3a0 00000001`4222e9c0     : 00000000`431b3910 00000000`0014f3d0 00000000`00000001 00000000`289d86f8 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1bc1b34
00000000`0014f3d0 00000001`41bb5b5a     : 00000000`515469a0 00000000`0014f428 00000000`2a591828 00000000`9e1ef700 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initlive_io+0x1fb060
00000000`0014f400 00000001`41bc1b34     : 00000000`2a591828 00000000`0014f530 00000000`00000000 00000000`53c48ce8 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1bb5b5a
00000000`0014f470 00000001`40db7782     : 00000000`00487476 00000000`22957edc 00000000`6b25e2e4 00000000`43197774 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1bc1b34
00000000`0014f4a0 00000001`4218eb68     : 00000000`53c48ce8 00000000`00000000 00000000`53c48ce8 00000000`0014f610 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0xdb7782
00000000`0014f4d0 00000001`416d8302     : 00000000`5cbb2d60 00000000`0014f610 00000000`00000000 00000000`53c48ce8 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initlive_io+0x15b208
00000000`0014f570 00000001`41bc6af7     : 00000000`06161644 00000000`0000000e 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014f690 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x16d8302
00000000`0014f5c0 00000001`40d673ee     : 00000000`15aa6924 00000000`53c48ce8 00000000`0014f690 00000000`0014f700 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x1bc6af7
00000000`0014f670 00000001`41c55307     : 00000000`0014f7f0 00000000`06b31988 00000000`9441b6d8 00000001`45ad4c08 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0xd673ee
00000000`0014f6b0 00000001`41c0e81c     : 00000394`00000434 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014f8d0 00000000`00000001 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x54587
00000000`0014f720 00000001`41c0f211     : 00000000`0000027f 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`00000008 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0xda9c
00000000`0014f780 00000001`41c61327     : 00000000`0014f808 00000000`0d956370 00000000`0014f8d0 00000000`00000001 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0xe491
00000000`0014f7d0 00000001`41c656e6     : 00000000`0d956370 00000000`0629ab30 00000000`0629ab30 00000000`000e0000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x605a7
00000000`0014f980 00000001`41c6bd5c     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`000e0001 00000000`004503a8 00000000`00000008 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x64966
00000000`0014faa0 00007ffd`a33a5c1d     : 00000000`0014fc18 00000001`40000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00006010 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x6afdc
00000000`0014fad0 00007ffd`a33a5612     : 00000000`00d41450 00000001`41c6bcf0 00000000`004503a8 00000000`0014fe48 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2bd
00000000`0014fc60 00000001`41c26f06     : 00000001`41c6bcf0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014fdb0 : user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1e2
00000000`0014fce0 00000001`416afca9     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00001fa0 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite!initAbletonIPC+0x26186
00000000`0014fea0 00000001`4157fd73     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x16afca9
00000000`0014fef0 00007ffd`a36c7c24     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ableton_Live_10_Suite+0x157fd73
00000000`0014ff30 00007ffd`a502d4d1     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000000`0014ff60 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


SYMBOL_NAME:  Ableton_Live_10_Suite+8b1b22

MODULE_NAME: Ableton_Live_10_Suite

IMAGE_NAME:  Ableton Live 10 Suite.exe

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_c0000005_Ableton_Live_10_Suite.exe!Unknown

OS_VERSION:  10.0.18362.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  1.0.0.1

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b5b87573-dea0-3dd7-1b04-5c3bde0dd978}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```